# Alien invasion that starts in a cabin in the woods

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie from around 15 years ago. There's a cabin in the forest. A stranger asks for help and uses bathroom. He emits a horrible smell and dies after ejecting a worm-like alien.  Aliens attempt to take over earth through water system.

In the end, an alien is headed for an opening in the floor of the water treatment facility in, Boston(?). Just as it approaches the edge, one of the two good guys from the cabin squashes it with his boot.

Comment: John, this has to be it!!  The description matches perfectly my memory of the movie. Thanks.

Comment: We've marked your question as a duplicate. It doesn't mean it's a bad question, just that we've had it before. Marking it as a Duplicate helps link it to the system so that the film gets suggested to people searching for it in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [*Dreamcatcher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcatcher_(2003_film)) (2003).

> One night, Jonesy sees Duddits beckoning him to cross the street, but
> as he does so, Jonesy is hit by a car. His injuries heal with
> mysterious speed, and six months later, he is able to make it for the
> group's annual trip. Jonesy rescues a man lost in the forest named
> Rick McCarthy. He is very ill, so Jonesy and Beaver let him rest and
> recover inside their cabin. Suddenly, all the forest animals—predator
> and prey both—run past their cabin in the same direction, followed by
> two military helicopters that announce the area is now quarantined.
> Jonesy and Beaver return to the cabin to find a trail of blood from
> the bedroom to the bathroom, where Rick sits dead, covered in blood. A
> three-foot long worm-like creature writhes and screams in the toilet.
> Beaver sits atop the toilet lid to trap the creature, but the creature
> breaks out and kills him. Jonesy tries to escape, but is confronted by
> a large alien called Mr. Gray, who possesses Jonesy's body.
>
> ... [At the end]
>
> Jonesy, now himself again, steps on the final alien larva before it can contaminate the reservoir.

Comment: I believe this is from Mr. King's Opioid Period.

Comment: How in the world did this get titled "Dreamcatcher"?

Comment: @Technophile - Feel free to [ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that as a question

Comment: @Technophile There's a line near the end of the book where it's revealed that one of the characters was immune to the alien, but was still able to be infected by it, because he believed that it could, and that thought stuck there like a dreamcatcher. Reportedly, the working title was *Cancer*. His wife, Tabitha, suggested the alternate title.

Comment: Is this the one with the butt snakes?